# A Question about the Toplogy of Weak Convergence

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, weak-convergence

I'm reading Royden, and am having trouble with the implication in bold below.

> If $\mathcal{F}$ is any collection of real-valued functions on a set $X$, the weak topology
> on $X$ induced by $\mathcal{F}$, or the $\mathcal{F}$-weak topology on X, is defined to be the weakest topology on $X$ (that is, the topology with the fewest number of sets) for which each function in $\mathcal{F}$ is continuous. A base at $x \in X$ for the $\mathcal{F}$-weak topology on $X$ comprises sets of the form $$\mathcal{N}_{f_1,..f_n,\epsilon} = \{x' \in X | \,\,\,|f_k(x) - f_k(x)| < \epsilon \text{ for } l < k < n\}$$
> **It is easy to see that a sequence $\{x_n\}$ in $X$ converges to $x \in X$ with respect to the $\mathcal{F}$-weak topology if and only if $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} f(x_n) = f(x) \, \forall f \in \mathcal{F}$**

I see the reverse implication. But I'm struggling with the forward implication. Starting with an arbitrary open set containing $x$ and all $x_n$ for $n > N$, we find a member of the basis contained in it so that it contains $x$ and some members of the sequence converging to it. This, however implies that $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} f_k(x_n) = f_k(x)$ for only finitely many $f_k \in \mathcal{F}$. How do we get  $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} f(x_n) = f(x)$ for all $f \in \mathcal{F}$?

Comment: In one word, when you chose an arbitrary open set. Or rather an arbitrary basic open set, you are chosing $f_{1},...,f_{n}$ arbitrarily. So your conclusion holds for any arbtirary choice of $f_{1},...,f_{n}$. So it holds for all $f$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The $\mathcal{F}$-weak topology is defined to be the weakest topology on $X$ **for which each function in $\mathcal{F}$ is continuous**.

By continuity, $f(x_n)\to f(x)$. So why is each $f$ continuous? Why does this *descriptive* definition match the *constructive* definition in terms of the $N_{f_1,f_2,\cdots,\epsilon}$?

*Fix* an $f\in\mathcal{F}$. We are given that $x_n\to x$ in the weak topology. Fix an $\epsilon>0$. I know that $N_{f,\epsilon}$ contains $x$, because $|f(x)-f(x)|=0<\epsilon$. $N_{f,\epsilon}$ is a weak neighbourhood of $x$, so by very definition of convergence (in topology) I know there is some $M\in\Bbb N$ such that $x_n\in N_{f,\epsilon}$ for all $n\ge M$.

But that means to say $|f(x_n)-f(x)|<\epsilon$ for all $n\ge M$ and such an $M$ always exists. $\epsilon>0$ could be any value whatsoever, so by definition of convergence in $\Bbb R$, $\lim_{n\to\infty}f(x_n)=f(x)$.

You might wonder why we bother with taking $N_{f_1,f_2,\cdots,f_k,\epsilon}$ for $k>1$, since we didn't need that in the above proof. That's because the axioms of topology force finite intersections of opens to be open, and $N_{f,\epsilon}\cap N_{g,\epsilon}=N_{f,g,\epsilon}$.

Answer (score 1):

In general, notice that

> Prop: If $\mathcal{S}$ is a subbasis for a Hausdorff topology $\tau$, then a sequence $x_n$ converges to $x$ iff for any $S\in\mathcal{B}$ containing $x$, there is $N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $x_n\in S$ whenever $n\geq N$.

Necessity is obvious for sabbatic sets are themselves elements of $\tau$. For sufficiency, let $U\in \tau$ containing $x$ (i.e. $U$ is a neighborhood of $x$). Since $\mathcal{S}$ is a basis, there are $V_1,\ldots, V_N$ in $\mathcal{S}$ such that $B=\bigcap^N_{j=1}V_j$ contains $x$ and $B\subset U$. By assumption, for each $1\leq j\leq N$  there is $N_j\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $x_n\in V_j$ whenever $n\geq N_j$. Let $N=\max_{1\leq j\leq N}N_j$. Then, if $n\geq N$, $x_n\in B\subset U$  that is, $x_n$ converges to $x$.

In the setting of the OP, if $\mathcal{F}$ is a collection of numerical (real or complex) functions on $X$ that separate points (i.e., whenever $x,y\in X$ and $x\neq y$, there is $f\in \mathcal{F}$ such that $f(x)\neq f(y)$, then the collection $\mathcal{S}$ of sets
$$B(x;f,\varepsilon)=\{y\in X: |f(x)-f(y)|<\varepsilon\},\qquad f\in\mathcal{F},\,\varepsilon>0$$
form a subbasis for a Hausdorff topology $\tau_\mathcal{F}$ on $X$. It easy to check that the  basis induced by $\mathcal{S}$ consists of all sets of the form
$$B(x;f_1,\ldots,f_N,\varepsilon)=\bigcap_{1\leq j\leq N}\{y\in X: |f_j(y)-f_j(x)|<\varepsilon\}$$
where $N\in\mathbb{N}$, $\{f_1,\ldots,f_N\}\subset \mathcal{F}$, and $\varepsilon>0$.

In view of the general statement above, a sequence $x_n$ converges to $x$ in the topology $\tau_\mathcal{F}$ iff for any subbasic set $B(x;f,\varepsilon)$, $f\in\mathcal{F}$ and $\varepsilon>0$, there is $N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $x_n\in B(x;f,\varepsilon)$ whenever $n\geq N$. In other words, $x_n$ converges to $x$ in $\tau_\mathcal{F}$ if for any $f\in\mathcal{F}$ and $\varepsilon>0$, there is $N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $|f(x_n)-f(x)|<\varepsilon$ whenever $n\geq N$, or equivalently,  $x_n$ converges to $x$ in $\tau_\mathcal{F}$ iff for any $f\in \mathcal{F}$, $f(x_n)$ converges to $f(x)$ in $\mathbb{R}$ (or $\mathcal{C}$).

---

Comments:

1. The Hausdorff condition is stated so that convergence in a topology makes sense (uniqueness).
2. The assumption that $\mathcal{F}$ separates points is to guarantee that the *weak topology* $\tau_\mathcal{F}$ is Hausdorff.
3. In general,  the *weak topology* $\tau_\mathcal{F}$ fails to be first countable in which case, the use of sequences to describe topological properties (closer for example) is not appropriate. In which case, it is better to use nets.
4. With minor modification to the proof the proposition above, one can substitute sequences by nets.
5. Using nets, one has that a net $x_\alpha$ converges to $x$ in
   $\tau_\mathcal{F}$ iff for any $f\in\mathcal{F}$, the net $f(x_\alpha)$ converges to $f(x)$ in $\mathbb{R}$ (or ($\mathbb{C}$).